# using multi-value parameter with delimited string in dataset

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2014

I have a table that contains a field with a delimited string, This is in fact a unsorted list of id's

```
id| name | valueslist
----------------------------------------------
1 | John | 46423423,36456325,76473234,98798796
2 | Mike | 36456325,98798796
3 | Sara | 46423423
```

I have a multi-value parameter based on a dataset that lists all possible id's

```
    param: @chosenvalues
    possible values: 
    46423423
    36456325
    76473234
    98798796
```

Now, when selecting on or more id's in the parameter, I want to return all records from my table that have that value present in their valueslist.

eg:

```
If I select 36456325 I need John & Mike to be returned
If I select 46423423 I need John & Sara to be returned
If I select 46423423 & 98798796 I need all three to be returned
```

I thought I could solve this like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE '%' + valueslist + '%' IN ('%' + @chosenvalues + '%')
```

but that doesn't work. Any suggestions as to how I could solve this?

TIA,

Henro

edit: I know this is in fact far from ideal modeling but unfortunately it is what I have to work with.

Comment: You should fix the data structure to have a junction table.  SQL has this great data structure for storing lists of things -- it is called a table, not a string.

Comment: It's incredible how often these types of questions show up. Bad data modelling is the root of all evil!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following SQL Select statement

```
/*
create table valueslisttbl (id smallint, name varchar(20), valueslist varchar(1000))
insert into valueslisttbl values 
(1, 'John', '46423423,36456325,76473234,98798796'),
(2, 'Mike', '36456325,98798796'),
(3, 'Sara', '46423423')
*/

declare @chosenvalues varchar(100)
--set @chosenvalues = '46423423'
--set @chosenvalues = '36456325'
--set @chosenvalues = '76473234'
set @chosenvalues = '46423423,98798796'

select distinct name
from valueslisttbl
cross apply dbo.Split(valueslisttbl.valueslist, ',') s
where s.val in (
    select val from dbo.Split(@chosenvalues, ',')
)
```

Also note that you need a [SQL Split function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx) in order to solve your requirement

I used SQL XML for the above SQL Server split function where you can find the SQL source codes at http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx

I hope it helps,

Comment: Another alternative to the split function: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Answer (score 1):

And suddenly I was struck by lightning and the idea came to me in a blinding flash of genius. (Well, it FELT that way anyway)

I joined the table with john's and janes  to the table with all the possible solutions. I then did a select distinct using a real standard where clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT j.*
FROM tableJohn j
LEFT JOIN Table_Solutions s on '%'+ s.value + '%' LIKE j.valuelist 
WHERE s.value in (@chosen_values)
```

@chosen_values could now nicely be populated with values from a multi-value parameter in a SSRS report.